# Starting process as post-build event makes main project wait until the launched procedd ends

Tags: visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

I am working on a program which connects to a live process in order to debug it using `ClrMD`.

I want to lunch the process as my post-build command of my main project, but when it start the process (which is a console application) my main project won't start until the lunched console application ends.

How can I launch the process as post build event without waiting for it to end?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use "start" to run your console application?If so,don't use "start".Try to call the console directly instead.